# Android: ListView with only one textview in each row cannot be clicked

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, textview

I can't click on any item in my list. My activity extends `ListActivity` and I have implemented the `OnItemClickListener` and set it to the list. I have researched the error and people had a similar issue with multiple views in the `listView` so by making `focusable` as false or  `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`.. usually solved their issue.. My problem is not getting solved.

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     movieListView = getListView(); // get the built-in ListView
     movieListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewMovieListener); 

     movieListView.setClickable(true);

     String[] from = new String[] { "name" };
     int[] to = new int[] { R.id.categoryTextView };
     movieAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter( MovieList.this, R.layout.activity_movie_list, null, from, to);

     value = getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.CATEGORY, -1);
     if(value == 1)
         category = "Family";
     else if(value == 2)
         category = "Horror";
     else if(value == 3)
         category = "Comedy";

}


 OnItemClickListener viewMovieListener = new OnItemClickListener() 
   {
      @Override
      // This doesnt get called? no it doesnt
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
         long id) 
      {
         // create an Intent to launch the ViewContact Activity
         Intent viewMovie = 
            new Intent(MovieList.this, ViewMovie.class);

         // pass the selected contact's row ID as an extra with the Intent
         viewMovie.putExtra(ROW_ID, id);
         startActivity(viewMovie); // start the ViewContact Activity
      } 
   };
```

My xml:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/categoryTextView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="TextView"
      android:focusable = "false"
      android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
      android:clickable="true"
      ></TextView>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `android:clickable="true"`?

Comment: it doesn't make a difference ,.. since I couldn't click on it .. i did that .. but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

In ListActivity, you can override onListItemClick to click Item

```
 @Override
 public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     Log.i("example",position);

 }
```

Comment: Is it supposed to be called automatically?

Comment: Yes, when you click item it will be called

Comment: You can look this tutorial http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView, android.view.View, int, long)

Comment: remove this and try again ?      android:focusable = "false"
      android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
      android:clickable="true"

Comment: I'm not sure but I never use that. Maybe you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski if this code solve his problem then it is answer. then no need to comment.

Comment: The formatting and *try this* looked as a request for clarification. Be more specific and offer a complete solution so the answer stands alone.

Comment: yes i knew formatting is not well above ans sorry for that. but it's specific and complete solution as per my view.

Comment: would you mind correcting the formatting and adding some more information so the answer attracts more eyes?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski i think answer is sufficient as per developer view